# Where can I get the chain vulcan?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Where can I get the chain vulcan? Do I have to be lucky and find it in a shop or are there other (possibly more reliable) ways to obtain one?

Comment: As per the game's XML, weapons have a rarity that determines how often they can be found (if at all! Some weapons are only available if you start with them!) But beyond that, there is no event or circumstance that lets you pick particular weapons over another, so it really is due to random chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah you just need to get lucky and find this in a shop it will cost 95 scrap when you do find it.

You have to be lucky due to the fact the game is mostly randomly generated when it comes to the shops so there is no reliable way to predict what a shop will have.